# Error in opening Microsoft Word through Terminal

Tags: terminal

I haven't been able to open Microsoft Word through Terminal.
I tried:

```
open -a Microsoft\Word
```

But I get this in return:

```
Unable to find application named 'MicrosoftWord'
```

How can I open Microsoft Word (I see it in Applications so I know it's installed)?

Comment: Why have you put a backslash in what you typed?

Comment: @Mark, He placed the backslash to escape the space in Microsoft Word but obviously forgot to type the space and for some reason couldn't figure it out from the error message. (That's my take on it anyway.)

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a space, it should be:

```
open -a Microsoft\ Word
```

Or:

```
open -a "Microsoft Word"
```

Program names that contain spaces need to be escaped with a `\` backslash or use `"` quotes around the name, but not both.